angular build failed error in kubernetes pod
I am getting this error when my webapp is running in kubernetes pod.
./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%2C%22runtimeErrors%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/.angular/cache/16.2.14/babel-webpack/8c4089325a41d7e6a0109ed788ace5297542e2aebbb21b82dfcf62b3aea46039.json'
There are 2 errors - build failed and unable to access file. I dont understand are they related or not? The file does not even exist they why is angular trying to access it 8c4089325a41d7e6a0109ed788ace5297542e2aebbb21b82dfcf62b3aea46039.json ? How can I fix the other error as well related to webpack-loader.js?
The errors and messages in the logs are very confusing. Just below the above error messages I see the following lines -
"** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **"
If there is a build error then why is the application live?
The pod is in running state despite the errors. And when hit the app url in the browser I get this error -
cannot GET /
Following is the environment info.
node v20.12.2
npm v10.5.0
ng  v16.2.12
Below is my docker file
FROM node:18
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

# Install Angular CLI globally
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Copy the entire Angular project to the container
COPY . .

# Build the Angular application
RUN npm run build

# Expose port 4200
EXPOSE 4200

# Start the Angular development server
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]


You're getting an EACCES error, which means your build is trying to write to a file or directory where you don't have permission to do so. In this case, it's probably the path "/app/.angular/cache/16.2.14...", and the problem is that it starts with /app. That implies a directory called "app" in the root directory, and your account probably cannot make directories there. It's likely that there's a typo in a configuration file, and it should be something like "./app" instead.
